# Prettytable module doesn't render properly when the numbers of rows are huge

Tags: python, prettytable

I am trying to print almost 100 rows using Prettytable to slack channel.

Before sending it to slack channel , I am modifying the table to string and sending ::
Finaltable = '````' + table.get_string() + '```'

But the data is very dislocated. It works fine when the rows are 20-30.
Is there any other module that can help me?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is : we can send max of 30 rows (including headers) to slack. Anything more than that would cause an error.
So i am splitting the entire table into sets of 30 rows (headers + data). Works fine for me,
Thanks